# How to change font in Wordpress header with zee style theme

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I am stuck, i have created a website with WordPress with zee style theme. I also applied a plugin named "FONT" to edit style sheet and apply custom font. All worked fine, my font was uploaded to the http://fontsforweb.com service from where i used to change the header.
After update of WordPress and the zee style theme all my work just gone and I am not able to use that font any more. The http://fontsforweb.com tried to help me, they made couple of updates with no positive result. So i remove that plugin and I tried to do it my self by converting my font to woff format and used the code below but still not working. I am afraid I will have to redo whole website. Please help me to avoid that.

Update: I played with other themes and the problem is exactly the same. In my opinion it's the WordPress it self making this problem.

`#logo h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "jadem___";
    src: url('jadem___.woff');
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to do this would be to create a child theme and edit your stylesheet from there. This article explains it better than I can [Tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/12/creating-your-first-wordpress-child-theme/)

This will sort of future-proof your theme and prevent it from changing if you update.

Also changing fonts is something you can do quite easily without a plugin. Again [someone else can explain this better than I can](http://wpmu.org/adding-custom-fonts-to-wordpress-with-font-face-and-css/)

THis may see like a dodgy answer, but I think if you check those links it will make sense. This is the correct way to handle this long term and it's easier than it looks. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

"Font" plugin is now using WOFF file formats so try again.